# Make XML Split view default in Android Studio 3.6+?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio 3.6 and above, an XML file always opens in the "Code" view by default. How do I make it open in "Split" view by default?

Comment: good question!!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Now for Android Studio "Arctic Fox" - `Preferences -> Editor -> Design Tools`. Nice!

[image]

---

In Android Studio 3.6 if you open `Preference->Editor->Layout editor` you can see for this case only check/uncheck `"Prefer XML editor"` for show modes `"Code" or "Design"` view without `"Split"`, very strange... Waiting for possibility check mode "Split"

**UPDATED**

Now Android Studio 4.0 has ***"Split"*** option. Nice!

[image]

Comment: Strange indeed. Let's hope they add the missing option soon.

Comment: This is the best option so far... Because `Design` form is too slow to open sometimes.

Comment: The split option is visible on `Android Studio 4.0 Beta 5`, Im not sure if it is on versions before this one.

Comment: AS 4.0 has solved the issue. It allows you to choose a default mode.

Comment: how to do it on 3.6? I dont see that option in layout editor

Comment: In Android Studio Arctic Fox: `Preferences -> Editor -> Design Tools`

Answer (score 4):

***2023 New UI Update***

I know this is not the exact answer for this one RE the default but in the new refreshed AS UI the selection to change with the editor open is on the top right of the open files tool bar.
Defaults are still under Design Tools in Settings.

[View switch for xml design and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxznd.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me, hope it works for you too.

1. Close all tabs in your editors.
2. Open one xml file and click on the split view button at the top-right section of the tab.
3. Close the tab again.

Android Studio then remembered my selection for all other tabs opened from then on.

Comment: I think Android Studio is remembering the selection for only that file. Other file still open with Design form...

Answer (score 0):

[image: keyMap for ShortCuts]
Using the keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl + Shift + Left/Right Arrow if you are on a Mac, or Alt + Shift + Left/Right Arrow otherwise):

- Code: provides the functionality of an XML text editor.
- Design: consists of a view containing the design editor (e.g. navigation graph, layout) that can be used to edit the file graphically.
- Split: displays both Code and Design side-by-side, so you can preview your design while editing the text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but AS 4.0 has solved the issue. It allows you to choose a default mode.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. You open another xml file from your Android studio who have left side xml.

Step 2. Then close all other tabs.

Step 3. Open Now It will show on left side.

Step 4. Because android studio remember last time xml open format.